# Maven project not treated as a java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have maven plugin installed for my eclipse of version (Oxygen).

I have the following added to my pom.xml -

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
<downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can go to my project and click Maven -> Update Project and it updates it.
Still it is not treated as a java project though. When I am trying add a new package or a class, I get the error "Source folder is not a Java project.". Could someone please provide me pointers? Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Right click on the project, go to properties, are there any "facets" for the project?

Comment: I don't have any facets configured for the project. What I found was, the submodule projects are found as maven projects  separately under Package Explorer. Those sub-modules are recognized as java projects.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't know what to do with maven parent directories because they don't contain code. You can import them as general projects if you wish but you shouldn't need to in practice

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a java project and right-click the project at Package-Explorer view, select Configure>Convert to Maven Project, then you can use maven dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was trying to import a github maven project directly into eclipse here. What I found was, the submodule projects are found as maven projects separately under Package Explorer. Those sub-modules are recognized as java projects.